# Extract data from one field into another in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, string

I have an old table which has a column like this

```
1 | McDonalds (Main Street)
2 | McDonalds (1st Ave)
3 | The Goose
4 | BurgerKing (Central Gardes)
...
```

I want to match the venues `like ' %(%)'` and then extract the content in the brackets to a second field 
to result in

```
1 | McDonalds | Main Street
2 | McDonalds | 1st Ave
3 | The Goose | NULL
4 | BurgerKing| Central Gardes
...
```

How would one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed these user defined functions

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Then I could select the "branches" via

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, preg_capture('/.*?\\((.*)\\)/',`name`,1) AS branch FROM `venues`
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) for [finding characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [extracting substrings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring). You can also use [control flow functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) to handle the cases where the venue is not present.